# Can't properly add addClass to code

Tags: jquery

I'm trying for a while now to make this code work I'm trying to change the first 3 lines of jquery to the next 3 ones and the css and jquery are included in the same php file

```
$('.nav li a').css("text-decoration", "none");
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    return false;

$('.nav li a').addClass("undnone");
    $(this).addClass("und");
    return false;
```

CSS

```
.und
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.undnone{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

here is the whole jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();

    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }

    $('.nav li a').addClass("undnone");
    $(this).addClass("und");
    return false;


});

});
```

html part with the menu

```
<ul class="nav" >
    <li><a href="champions.php">Champions</a></li>
    <li><a href="items.php">Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="changes.php">Changes</a></li>
    </ul>
   <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

Comment: I didn't copy I rewrote the code so in my code there is " after und and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please provide a complete code (HTML, JS, etc.) example so that we can recreate the issue. A jsFiddle.net example is usually very useful.

Comment: First of all, you need functions not the result of their invocation `function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);/*here*/
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader);/*and here*/
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `undnone` class in addition to adding the `und` class.

`$(this).removeClass("undone").addClass("und");`

Otherwise, they're both still being applied, and the `und` class doesn't automatically take priority.

The reason that the old/original way you were doing it works is because you are actually setting/overwriting the value of the `text-decoration` for the element, instead of simply adding a class.

Answer (score 0):

Generally bad idea to use classes for single css-properties. You kinda loosing semantics and such. You can use single and more meaningful class `active` instead.

```
var active = 'active';
$('.nav li a' + '.' + active).removeClass(active);
$(this).addClass(active);
```

And CSS

```
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And by the way you need callback not the results.

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent); //no parenthesis here
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').show('normal', hideLoader); //and here
}
```